# Same Origin Workaround for REST API

Tags: json, rest, header, jsonp, same-origin-policy

A consumer is trying to call my REST API from client-side code (Javascript / Jquery). Now, as expected - they receive a security error because of the Same Origin Policy.

I know one workaround is for the API to respond with JSON-P.

Would adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` to the header also fix the issue? Is it a better workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a specific list of domains that you want to allow access from while restricting access from all other domains I would stick with JSON-P. In my experience CORS has spotty browser support and can be finicky to implement.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using the header but indeed it is very spotty. Ended up using JSONP